# Routing problem in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am new to ruby on rails. 
I used the command 'rails generate controller Courses new'

Then, I edited routes.rb file with:

```
  resources :courses
  match '/courses', :to => 'courses#new'
```

When I access http://0.0.0.0:3000/courses. I get an error:

Unknown action

The action 'index' could not be found for CoursesController.

I think i am missing something. Please help

Thanks.

Comment: can you go to your rails folder in the command prompt and run 'rake routes' to see the existing routes. Can you paste the output here?  My guess is 'new' by default requires an id to work on. But have not yet worked on rails 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

resources :courses generates the routes for courses like so:

```
/courses -> coursescontroller#index

/courses/:id -> coursescontroller#show
...
```

and so on. This is known as 'restful routes'.

If you do not want to direct a url of form 'courses.html' to the 'index' action of your courses controller, but to the 'new' action of your courses controller (which would be highly unusual, by the way), just remove the first line from your routes.rb.

If you want to see what routes you have defined, just do

```
rake routes
```

from your rails app directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this instead:

```
resources :courses, :except => :index
match '/courses', :to => 'courses#new'
```

The `except` option takes a symbol or an array of actions in the controller you do not want to define resource routes for. In this case, we turn off the route for the `index` action, `/courses/`.

Next, we define the same route that would have been defined for the `index` action, but point it at `CoursesController#new`.

Answer (score 0):

Put your "match" line before your "resources" line.